# Unnamed error using Urllib2 and Beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2, scraper

The output of this code block always returns me the "except". No specific error is shown in my terminal. What am i doing wrong ?
Any help is appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib2

# get page source and create a BeautifulSoup object based on it
try:
    print("Fetching page.")
    page = urllib2.open("http://siph0n.net")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    #specify tags the parameters are stored in
    metaData = soup.find_all("a")
except:
    print("Error during fetch.")
    exit()
```

Comment: You are not printing the error, see @DeepSpace answer. Also `open` is not a function of urllib2.

Comment: If you are not sure about your code working fine or not, please don't use `try/except` covered the core block, even worse, not print the error message.

Answer (score 0):

> "No specific error is shown in my terminal"

That's because your `except` block is shadowing it. Either remove the `try/except` or print the exception in the `except` block:

```
try:
    .
    .
    .
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Note that catching the general type `Exception` is generally a bad idea. Your `except` blocks should always catch the specific exception type as possible.

Comment: The error was that open was not a function of urllib2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use requests for getting the data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import urllib2
# get page source and create a BeautifulSoup object based on it
try:
    print("Fetching page.")
    page = requests.get("http://siph0n.net")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

    #specify tags the parameters are stored in
    metaData = soup.find_all("a")
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Comment: Thank you, this gave me the error and it is fixed now.